# Collection is not getting created even after creating the model using mongoose

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, angularjs-directive, mongoose-schema

I have created a model using mongoose.
However, it is not creating collection in mongodb.
My connection is working fine though to the mongodb

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

const conn = require('app/connection');

var notesSchema = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    message: String,
});

var dataSchema = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    dataId: String,
    dataName: String,
    notes: [notesSchema]
}, {
    collection: 'dataCols'
});

var dataCol = conn.on('cg').model('dataCol', dataSchema);
```

I have also tried acting against the model (find, insert etc) but the collection is not created automatically.

I am connecting to a replica set

Comment: Are you connecting to a standalone instance, or a replica set?

Comment: Why do you bother with `_id: ObjectId`? They would be created for you anyway automatically. Each collection must have one regardless. Its a MongoDB tihing. Unless I am missing something ...

Comment: I am connecting to a replica set